# how to change jupyer notebook code font to bold

Tags: jupyter-notebook

anybody know how to change jupyter notebook code cells to bold like this?
[image]

because now i have not standart jupyter font size and don't know why

now i have font like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of the notebook is styled using CSS. If you want to customise it then you need to create a custom style sheet.

Create a `custom` folder in the Jupyter profile folder, usually `~/.jupyter/custom/`.

Within this folder create a `custom.css` file and add your custom CSS to it.

```
    .code_cell {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

Changes should take effect the next time you open Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter Notebook uses `css` for styling.

In order to have code font displayed in `bold`, you have to edit the `custom.css` file in the `jupyter` directory.

The `css` portion that defines the code font `weight` is the following:

```
}
HTML,
body,
div,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ul,
ol,
li,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
pre,
code,
form,
fieldset,
legend,
input,
button,
textarea,
p,
blockquote,
th,
td,
span,
a {
text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
font-weight: 400;
}
```

Just change the `font-weight` declaration from `font-weight: 400;` to `font-weight: bold;`.

Comment: I am sure this answer is helpful, however: in general it's a numerical value for font-weight is valid. Perhaps explain - if you can - why this is not the case here (e.g. if the CSS interpreter is not modern enough to accept numerical values) or point to the excerpt of the documentation to read up on this matter in.

Comment: @Igor You're right that the font-weight property accepts numerical values as well. In my original answer, I used `font-weight: bold`, which is equivalent to `font-weight: 700`. 

To clarify, you can use a numerical value instead of 'bold'. For example, you can set the font-weight to 700 or any other value between 100 (thin) and 900 (heavy) to adjust the font weight according to your preference.